# How to get file names for attachments in nodemailer

Tags: javascript, meteor, email-attachments, nodemailer, data-uri

I am sending email with attachment using nodemailer, When I assign path as base64 datauri and filename as "filename.txt" then received mail contains attachment with name as "attachment-1.pdf",
I want name as "filename.pdf"

```
attachments = [{filename : "filename1.pdf", path : dataUri1},{filename : "filename2.pdf", path:dataUri2}]
var mailOptions = {
            from: from, 
            to: to, 
            subject: subject, 
            html: text, 
            cc : cc,
            attachments :attachments
        };
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, response){})
```